# Is it possible to compile a single tr with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my directive I have a template for a row of a table. I want to compile it and bind it to the data of the row. If I compile the **tr** it is converted to a span. If I compile a **li** or a **h1** everyting is fine.

```
// the tr is unfortunatly thrown away     
$compile('<tr><td>{{item.id}}</td></tr>')
// h1 works
$compile('<h1>{{item.id}}</h1>')
// li works
$compile('<li>{{item.id}}</li>')
```

If I debug into $compile() it seems that `$compileNodes = jqLite($compileNodes);` "cleans" the template. Is there a workaround?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There may be more 'angular' way to get it done that doesn't require calling $compile directly.

Comment: I agree with @SMcCrohan. By the way, maybe your problem is that tr tag without a wrapping table tag is meaningless.